# Jquery Datepicker on Repeating Fields

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I know this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to get previous answers to work as my code is a bit different.

So I have a repeating field that I am trying to use datepicker on.  The first instance works fine, if I add a line however, the datepicker displays on another part of the screen and does not enter any information into the field when clicked.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.metabox_submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#publish').click();
    });
    $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
        var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
        row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
        row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
        return false;
    });
    $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        return false;
    });
    $('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody').sortable({
        opacity: 0.6,
        revert: true,
        cursor: 'move',
        handle: '.sort'
    });

    $('.session-time').timepicker({
        'minTime': '8:00am',
        'maxTime': '10:0pm',
        'step': 15,
    });

    $('.session-date').each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,  
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        yearRange: '2017:2020'
        });
    });
});
</script>

});
</script>
<div class="wrap">
<table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" class="form-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Remove</th>
            <th>Session Date</th>
            <th>Session Time</th>
            <th>Sort</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    if ( $repeatable_fields ) :
        foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) : // there are complete fields
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="session-date" name="session_date[]" value="<?php if($field['session_date'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['session_date'] ); ?>" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="session-time" name="session_time[]" value="<?php if($field['session_time'] != '') echo esc_attr( $field['session_time'] ); ?>" /></td>
            <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
        </tr>


    <?php endforeach; 
        else : // show a blank one ?>

        <tr>
            <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="session-date" name="session_date[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="session-time" name="session_time[]" /></td>
            <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
        </tr>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- empty hidden one for jQuery -->

        <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">
            <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">-</a></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="session-date" name="session_date[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="session-time" name="session_time[]" /></td>
            <td><a class="sort">|||</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who comes upon this issue, here is the fix that worked for me.  I was able to get this work for datapicker, but not for timepicker.

```
$(document).on('focus', '.session-date', function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,  
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        yearRange: '2017:2020
    });
});
```

Just use the code in place of

```
$('.session-date').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,  
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        yearRange: '2017:2020'
    });
});
```